# Showing normality with just generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H = \langle S \rangle$ be a subgroup of $G = \langle T \rangle$. Prove that $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $tst^{-1} \in H$ for all $s \in S$ and $t \in T \cup T^{-1}$. Here $T^{-1}$ denotes the set $T^{-1}=\{t^{-1} \mid t\in T\}$.

This is a result my text uses but does not prove, and I am curious to see how it should be done rigorously.

Comment: One direction is clear. To prove $(\Leftarrow)$ try writing arbitrary elements of $G,H$ in terms of elements of $S,T$.

Comment: What are you studying?
What text is this drawn from?
What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?
Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set $K$ of all $g\in G$ such that $gHg^{-1}=H$.  Note that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ (indeed, it is the kernel of the action of $G$ on the set of conjugates of $H$, by conjugation).  By definition, $H$ is normal iff $K=G$.

Now suppose $tst^{-1}\in H$ for all $s\in S$ and all $t\in T\cup T^{-1}$.  Since $S$ generates $H$ and conjugation by $t$ is a homomorphism, this implies $tht^{-1}\in H$ as well for all $h\in H$ and $t\in T\cup T^{-1}$.  Fixing any $t\in T$, this says that $tHt^{-1}\subseteq H$.  Letting $u=t^{-1}$, we also have $uHu^{-1}\subseteq H$, and conjugating both sides by $t$ we get $H\subseteq tHt^{-1}$.  Thus $H=tHt^{-1}$, so $t\in K$.  Since $t\in T$ was arbitrary, this proves $T\subseteq K$.  Since $K$ is a subgroup, this means $K=G$ and so $H$ is normal.